# How to write Sql query for a survey form whit many rbls that rbls are not equal?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tab like this:

[image: mytable]

now I want to write a query with below output:

```
----------------------------------------------
Tags    rbl1    rbl2    rbl3........rbl12
----------------------------------------------  
a       Int      Int    Int .......  Int 
b       Int      Int    Int .......  Int 
c       Int      Int    Int .......  Int 
d       Int      Int    Int .......  Int 
e       Int      Int    Int .......  Int
```

The number of NULL values should be count.

Comment: Where does the value of `Tags` come from. What's wrong with a simple `CASE` expression here? Also, your design look like it's suffering from significant denormalisation issues.

Comment: Also, why do you want to return the data type for each row? A Column can only have one datatype, so return the datatype per row seems pointless; as it's not going to change,.

Comment: values of tags come from another table

Comment: So how do *we* get that value when it isn't in your sample data? What is the relationship? How you get from one result to the other is completely unclear.

Comment: I want to return the sum of each tags responds

Comment: So how do the tags relate? How does the Sum of numbers become `'int'`? What numbers do add to get the `varchar` value `'int'`?

Comment: form id is the relationship

Comment: for each rble should calculate how many 1, how many 2...

Comment: but `'int'` isn't a number, it's a string... What you ask doesn't make sense. YOur sample data lacks values like `'a'`, `'b'` and you say the sum of some digits is the word `'int'`. No numbers added together make the string `'int'`.

Comment: you do not need to sum 'int'.for example, it needs to calculate how many 0, 1, 2, 3 or NULL are voted for 'rbl1' and so on

Comment: I think you want to unpivot the data by rbl and then re-pivot by survey values some of which are null because this is a non-normalized design.

Comment: Please add the Form Id to the data

Comment: Why Form id? it can help to solve the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tags table
(
id int,
taglabel char(1)
);

insert into @tags(id, taglabel)
values(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f');


declare @r table
(
rbl1 int,
rbl2 int,
rbl3 int,
rbl4 int,
rbl5 int,
rbl6 int,
rbl7 int,
rbl8 int,
rbl9 int,
rbl10 int,
rbl11 int,
rbl12 int
);

insert into @r(rbl1, rbl2, rbl3, rbl4, rbl5, rbl6, rbl7, rbl8, rbl9, rbl10, rbl11, rbl12)
values
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 1),
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0),
(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6);


select 
    case when p.thetagid = -1 then cast('No tag/NULL' as varchar(20)) else isnull(cast(t.taglabel as varchar(20)), 'missing tag?') end as thetaglabel,
    p.*
from 
(
select 
    isnull(rbl1, -1) as rbl1, isnull(rbl2, -1) as rbl2, isnull(rbl3, -1) as rbl3, isnull(rbl4, -1) as rbl4, isnull(rbl5, -1) as rbl5,
    isnull(rbl6, -1) as rbl6, isnull(rbl7, -1) as rbl7, isnull(rbl8, -1) as rbl8, isnull(rbl9, -1) as rbl9, isnull(rbl10, -1) as rbl10, 
    isnull(rbl11, -1) as rbl11, isnull(rbl12, -1) as rbl12  
from @r
)
as r
unpivot
(
thetagid for therbl in (rbl1, rbl2, rbl3, rbl4, rbl5, rbl6, rbl7, rbl8, rbl9, rbl10, rbl11, rbl12)
) as unp
pivot
(
count(unp.therbl) for unp.therbl in (rbl1, rbl2, rbl3, rbl4, rbl5, rbl6, rbl7, rbl8, rbl9, rbl10, rbl11, rbl12)
) as p
left join @tags as t on p.thetagid = t.id;
```